# Data Table Copy not showing properly in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a stored procedure which actually concatenates 2 columns and returns a `DataTable`.
Its as below:

```
create procedure [dbo].[spEnqIDFyYear]
as
begin
select CONVERT(nvarchar(50),enq_id)+'/'+CONVERT(nvarchar(50),YEAR(fy_year)) as EnqIDFyYear from Sample.dbo.enquiry_details
end
GO
```

The output is as follows:

```
EnqIDFyYear
1/2015
2/2014
```

I have another procedure, whose output is as below:

```
profile_name
ProfileA
ProfileB
```

I bind both the procedures to 2 `DataTables`, merge those 2 `DataTables` into a 3rd one and bind the resulting `DataTable` to the `gridview`.

But the gridview is not showing as proper. It shows as below:
[image]

The rows should be aligned to each other. How to achieve it?

Code behind is as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = PopulateDashBoardGrid1();
            DataTable dt2 = PopulateDashBoardGrid2();
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            dt3 = dt1.Copy();
            dt3.Merge(dt2);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt3;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        //Populate the main DashBoard Grid
        public DataTable PopulateDashBoardGrid1()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spEnqIDFyYear", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

        }

        public DataTable PopulateDashBoardGrid2()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spClientProfileName", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

        }
```

Experts please help.

Regards
Anurag

Comment: you are not Opening your connection. Don't you get any error?

Comment: @Selman22 - Its not required for disconnected data access.

Comment: @nurag from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx): _Clone creates a new DataTable with the same structure as the original DataTable, but does not copy any data (the new DataTable will not contain any DataRows). To copy both the structure and data into a new DataTable, use [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)_.

Comment: @dkozl: Yeah i realized it. have edited the question to use Copy(). But the gridview doesn't show properly. Can you please have a look at the question again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that kind of output, because [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works in that way if the columns are not same of two datatables. So you need to write some custom code.

Here is what I have:-

```
static DataTable MergeDataTables(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
     DataTable dt3 = dt1.Copy();
     foreach (DataColumn dc in dt2.Columns)
     {
         dt3.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName).DataType = dc.DataType;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < dt3.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         foreach (DataColumn dc in dt2.Columns)
         {
             string col = dc.ColumnName;
             dt3.Rows[i][col] = dt2.Rows[i][col];
         }
     }
     return dt3;
}
```

You can call this method to merge both datatables.

Comment: Let me try this Mr. Rahul.

Comment: Amazing Mr. Rahul..it works perfectly. What if I need to merge some 9-10 data tables. I will get this requirement later in the day. How should the above code be altered for that?

Comment: @Anurag - You're welcome. 9-10 tables into 1? That too with different columns? I think you will have to call this method again & again, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Ohh..so you mean to say..once dt1 and dt2 are merged into dt3, i will call this method with merged dt3 and new dt4..correct? Yeah.I need to show a grid, which has 10 columns, and all those 10 columns are calculated based upon certain conditions in sql. So I have written diff procedures and calling them to bind them in diff datatables.

Comment: @Anurag - Yeah exactly! But like I said I am not sure if this is the best approach. Why don't you do all these stuff in SQL database itself, there you can call multiple `proc` and then return single result back.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should try that. Anyways I have sent you a invitation on Linkedin. Please do accept that. This is the 2nd time you have helped me over here. Anyways can i have ur emailid?? :)Thanks